# vcvarsall.bat not found - python

Tags: python

My OS is windows 8 and python version is 3.4, Microsoft visual studio 11.0 .

While trying to install mod_wsgi I am getting vcvarsall.bat not found. I have changed my environment variables VS100COMNTOOLS value to VS110COMNTOOLS. But still getting same error.

I tried to install SDK for windows8 and .netframework 4.0 but it failed.

In my system I have following .net folder: `C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET` under this I have following folders : `assembly; authman; Framework; Framework64`.

I also have `Microsoft.Net` folder in `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft.NET`.
I installed Windows kit under same folder.
I tried to resolved the problem using `nmake -f ap24py34-win64-VC10`.

It's giving the following error:
`v1077: "c:\program Files <x86>\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\VC\BIN\c1.Exe":return code '0x2' stop.`

Please help me to fix this problem
Thanks in advance

Comment: This isn't much related to Python, it's rather a problem with your VC configuration.

Comment: Consider adding more tags that are relevant to the question.

Answer (score 0):

According to [this page](https://wiki.python.org/moin/WindowsCompilers#Which_Microsoft_Visual_C.2B-.2B-_compiler_to_use_with_a_specific_Python_version_.3F) python 3.4 needs Visual C++ 10.0. You actually need it installed. If you read further down the page, you'll find a link to a standalone distro provided by MS. Installing this should fix the problem.

Comment: thank you for the answer, but couldn't find the link specified by you

Comment: Even i tried to install vc++ 10.0 but its giving an error saying SDk7.1 was not installed. I already have .net framework 4.5 SDK